# How can I add a submenu in admin panel under a existing menu in NopCommerce 3.8?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, menu, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.80

My question is almost similar like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510580/add-submenu-in-admin-panel-in-nopcommerce-3-8) except a little bit change. There is a solution for adding menu, like I also want to add menu but in a different process.

Currently I am developing a project on combo promotional offer. So therefore I want to add a sub menu under `Promotion` Like all other submenus [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDQea.png)

But what I have developed is creating a separate menu named `Plugins` and adding a submenu there. Like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEZFO.png)

And here is the code I have used for creating that menu.

```
public void ManageSiteMap(SiteMapNode rootNode)
        {
            var menuItem = new SiteMapNode()
            {
                SystemName = "Promotion.Combo",
                Title = "Combo Offer",
                ControllerName = "PromotionCombo",
                ActionName = "Configure",
                Visible = true,
                RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary() { { "area", null } },
            };
            var pluginNode = rootNode.ChildNodes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SystemName == "Third party plugins");
            if (pluginNode != null)
                pluginNode.ChildNodes.Add(menuItem);
            else
                rootNode.ChildNodes.Add(menuItem);
        }
```

I would like to know from which `SystemName` shall I add this submenu?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41519284/2534646) answer hope it'll help

Comment: Did you read my question thoroughly ?? I have mentioned this question in the beginning of my question. Please check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
public void ManageSiteMap(SiteMapNode rootNode)
{
    var menuItem = new SiteMapNode()
    {
       SystemName = "Promotion.Combo",
       Title = "Combo Offer",
       ControllerName = "PromotionCombo",
       ActionName = "Configure",
       IconClass = "fa-dot-circle-o"
       Visible = true,
       RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary() { { "area", null } },
    };

    var pluginNode = rootNode.ChildNodes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SystemName == "Promotions");
        if (pluginNode != null)
            pluginNode.ChildNodes.Add(menuItem);
        else
            rootNode.ChildNodes.Add(menuItem);
}
```

System name you looked for is

> Promotions

Updated answer to show you can use the IconClass in your menuItem object to add the icon in front of the menu item name.

Also, just for completeness, don't forget to add IAdminMenuPlugin to your plugin cs file, like so:

```
public class MyCustomPlugin : BasePlugin, IAdminMenuPlugin
```

Comment: Hi @Div. Thanks for the comment but I must disagree. NopCommerce re-evaluates ManageSiteMap method of each active plugin every time admin page is being rendered. So if your plugin is disabled (uninstalled) menu item will disappear since it has not been added again for the request. Also for performance be careful not to write non-performant code at ManageSiteMap otherwise admin side page rendering will be more slow. BTW thanks a lot for the edit my friend :)

Comment: Yes, of course. It disappeared. I also debugged the ManageSiteMap to reverse engineer and verify plugin loading mechanism. For anyone in interest, the code which constructs left admin menu Admnistration/Views/Shared/menu.cshtml under Nop.Web project.

Comment: It's working fine, but there is a icon ahead of the list, but on, my custom menu it's not available.

Comment: @Shoumen Agdm you can add IconClass = "fa-dot-circle-o" inside the menuItem SiteMapNode object